# Networkx bug? color is misplaced

Tags: python-3.x, colors, networkx

I people, I'm trying to plot a network graph using networkx module, but I am having results I was not expecting and I am starting to ask myself if it is any module issue!

I have this code inside a class:

```
def plotGraph(self):
    conn = []
    nodeLabel = {}

    for node_idx in self.operatorNodes:
        print("i = ", node_idx)
        print(self.node[node_idx].childs)
        for child in self.node[node_idx].childs:
            conn.append((child.idx, node_idx))

    for i in range(self.nn):
        nodeLabel[i] = str(i) + ": " + self.node[i].opString

    node_color = ['blue'] * self.nn
    #for i in range(self.nOutputs):
    #    node_color[i] = 'red'

    node_color[0] = 'red'

    print('Graph Conn = ', conn)
    print('Graph Color = ', node_color)
    # you may name your edge labels
    labels = map(chr, range(65, 65 + len(conn)))
    print('nodeLabel = ', nodeLabel)

    draw_graph(conn, nodeLabel, node_color=node_color, labels=labels)
```

From the prints I can see that what is being passed inside the draw_graph is (draw_graph code is based in https://www.udacity.com/wiki/creating-network-graphs-with-python):

```
Graph Conn =  [(2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 1), (5, 1), (6, 2), (7, 2), (8, 5), (9, 5)]
Graph Color =  ['red', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue']
nodeLabel =  {0: '0: mul', 1: '1: mul', 2: '2: mul', 3: '3: cte', 4: '4: cte', 5: '5: sum', 6: '6: cte', 7: '7: cte', 8: '8: cte', 9: '9: cte'}
```

[Yet the plot is the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlxB3.png)

draw_graph code is:

```
def draw_graph(graph, nodeLabel, node_color, labels=None, graph_layout='shell',
               node_size=1600, node_alpha=0.3,
               node_text_size=12,
               edge_color='blue', edge_alpha=0.3, edge_tickness=1,
               edge_text_pos=0.3,
               text_font='sans-serif'):

    # create networkx graph
    G=nx.DiGraph()

    # add edges
    for edge in graph:
        G.add_edge(edge[0], edge[1])

    # these are different layouts for the network you may try
    # shell seems to work best
    if graph_layout == 'spring':
        graph_pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
    elif graph_layout == 'spectral':
        graph_pos = nx.spectral_layout(G)
    elif graph_layout == 'random':
        graph_pos = nx.random_layout(G)
    else:
        graph_pos = nx.shell_layout(G)

    # draw graph
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, graph_pos, width=edge_tickness, alpha=edge_alpha, edge_color=edge_color)
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, graph_pos, labels=nodeLabel, font_size=node_text_size, font_family=text_font)

    if labels is None:
        labels = range(len(graph))

    edge_labels = dict(zip(graph, labels))
    nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, graph_pos, edge_labels=edge_labels, label_pos=edge_text_pos)

    nx.draw(G, graph_pos, node_size=node_size, alpha=node_alpha, node_color=node_color)
```

Has can be seen, the Graph Color in 0 position is red and the remain should be blue, yet the plot is putting in the third node! There is no way for me to access node 1 has well, apparently, nodes are misplaced! The nodes color are placed in the following positions [2, 0, 3, 4, 5,....].

Comment: You're consistent, but `edge_tickness` should probably be `edge_thickness`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `nx.draw` and pass it an (optional) list of colors, it will assign those colors to the nodes in the same order as the (optional) `nodelist`.  But you didn't define `nodelist`.  So it will default to whatever order comes out of `G.nodes()`.

Since the underlying data structure for a networkx graph is a dictionary, you have to deal with the fact that you [cannot count on the nodes to have any specified order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary).

Try passing `nodelist` into the `nx.draw` command in the order you want.